# How are phone numbers used in Twilio Programmable Voice SDK for Android?

Tags: android, twilio

I am using the [Android Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/android) to build an app where one user can call another app user. Calls can only be made to other app users (by searching their username and calling them with a simple click).

(1) In this scenario, are each users provided with a Twilio phone number?

(2) Say user A calls user B. How does Twilio know that user A is calling user B? (Both a general AND technical explanation would be really helpful here). What is the workflow from making that call to answering it?

The current documentation on the Voice API doesn't explain its technical use in conjunction with Android except for the quickstart Android project on github. However, as this is focused more on implementation rather than technical explanation, there are a few aspects I am still trying to understand like phone numbers not seemingly being used and the other points mentioned above.

Comment: Do you want your users to use their data/wifi connection to make those calls to each other? Or do you want them to be able to make the calls without using their data/wifi? If they can use data/wifi, then there is no reason to go through the public switched telephone network, and they can just use Twilio as the go-between.

Comment: Users are able to use their data/wifi to make calls (in fact, it should be the only way). How exactly would Twilio work as a go-between then? I've read the documentation but I'm still unclear on the overall workflow from making that call (user A), to Twilio registering/detecting it, forwarding it to user B and user B answering it.

Comment: I've actually seen this video and other tips as well, but it's too high level. I'm looking for something more technical and also specific to Android as it [differs](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/tree/master/app) a certain amount including for the api call. For example the Android Studio code doesn't seem to be using a phone number unlike what the video shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are making app to app calls, your users do not need a phone number. Instead they are identified by the identity that you provide for the user when you generate an access token for them or when you create a push credential (as Stephan points out).

When you [create an access token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens) for your app's user, you provide a TwiML application SID. That TwiML application defines the URL that Twilio will make a request to when placing outbound calls.

When you place a call with the Voice SDK you pass a set of params to the `connect` method:

```java
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("to", contact.getText().toString());
ConnectOptions connectOptions = new ConnectOptions.Builder(accessToken)
    .params(params)
    .build();
Voice.connect(VoiceActivity.this, connectOptions, callListener);
```

You can send any params you like, in the example above we send a param called "to" with a string from an input field in the view. When you place the call, Twilio then sends those parameters to that URL set in the TwiML application.

When your application receives that webhook it needs to return TwiML to Twilio to tell Twilio what to do next. In your case, you need to return TwiML that will use [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) and [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client) to connect to another application. In this case, you would take the incoming param "to", as defined above, and use it as the client identity you want to call.

```xml
<Response>
   <Dial>
     <Client>
        <Identity>IDENTITY_FROM_PARAMS</Identity>
      </Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

That way Twilio will connect the dialling application to the receiving application identified by the identity.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. The documentation and the code make a lot more sense now. When creating the URL for the TwiML application, do I need to provide my own URLs or does Twilio provide available URLs? It looks like [TwiML Bins](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/tutorials/twiml-bins) are used to do the latter?

Comment: For a simple implementation, you could certainly do it with TwiML Bins using their [templating feature](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/230878368-How-to-use-templates-with-TwiML-Bins). If you needed to do anything more complicated you could use [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) or your own URL in your own application.